# How to find not commented commands in source code using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find the **"source"** command and take its argument. The problem is that the code may be commented out, in that case, it is necessary to ignore it. Comments begin with a “#”.

The code example:

**Match cases:**

```
source run.sh
source /path/run3.sh # comment
echo "Msg"; source ./run4.changelist
other_command_1; other_command_2; ... ; other_command_n; source ./run4.changelist
    source run.changelist
```

**Don't match cases:**

```
# source run.changelist
# source /path/run3.sh # comment
echo "Msg"; # source ./run4.changelist
other_command; # source ./run4.changelist
other_command # source ./run4.changelist
other_command_1; other_command_2; ... ; other_command_n # source ./run4.changelist
    # source run.changelist
```

I wrote one version but it doesn’t cover everything:

`^(?!\s*#)(?!.*;).*source\s+((.*.sh)|(.*.changelist))`

Comment: The regular expressions alone **are not powerful enough** to solve this problem, in general. They can be used to identify the simple examples you posted but they are not enough for something like `echo "#"; source ./run4.changelist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that probably only a language parser can fully address, but you can make an approximation by first matching all you don't want, then capturing only what you do want in alternation. For example:

```py
r='"{3}.*?"{3}|#[^"\'\n]*|source ([^\n#]*)'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NtzIss/1).

Code example:

```
regex = r'"{3}.*?\"{3}|#[^"\'\n]*|source ([^\n#]*)'
matches = re.findall(regex, your_text, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```py
['run.sh', '/path/run3.sh ', '', './run4.changelist', './run4.changelist',
 'run.changelist', '', './run4.changelist', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

You'd now have to act on all non-empty captures either by filtering or iteration, etc.

Edit: I should probably have added a filter example:

```py
filter(lambda c: c != '', matches)
```

Comment: Clever solution.

Comment: @axiac It's one of those old patterns that still fits quite well every once in a while. :)